# XLSX file corrupted on download in Vuejs&Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, download, xlsx

I have an API (Rails) response **binary** file

```rb
def download_result
  data = ...
  send_data(
    data,
    filename: 'test.xlsx',
    type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
  )
 end
```

At Vuejs, I want to download this file by below code

```js
downloadResult ({ commit, dispatch, rootGetters }, id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dispatch('downloadResult', { id })
    .then(response => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response]))
        const link = document.createElement('a')
        link.href = url
        link.setAttribute('download', 'test.xlsx')
        document.body.appendChild(link)
        link.click()
    })
  })
}
```

- The API response is OK, and if I open this API on new tab, it will download file OK => I can open it in Excel.[image]
- However, if I open the result after download from Vuejs, it will **corrupted**

I tried some solutions but they still error.

Hope some help from everyone.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct, you just need to make sure that the API response is correct, otherwise I think there is nothing else you can do.

```
downloadResult ({ commit, dispatch, rootGetters }, id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dispatch('downloadResult', { id })
      .then(response => {
        const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: response.headers['content-type'] })

        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)

        const link = document.createElement('a')
        link.href = url
        link.setAttribute('download', 'test.xlsx')

        document.body.appendChild(link)
        link.click()

        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
        document.body.removeChild(link)

        resolve()
      })
      .catch(error => {
        reject(error)
      })
  })
}
```

also you can try this with `axios`:

```
import axios from 'axios'

downloadResult ({ commit, dispatch, rootGetters }, id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios({
      url: 'your_api_endpoint_here',
      method: 'GET',
      responseType: 'blob', 
      params: { id } // if you need to pass 'id' as a query parameter
    })
      .then(response => {
        const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: response.headers['content-type'] })

        const link = document.createElement('a')
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        link.setAttribute('download', 'test.xlsx')

        document.body.appendChild(link)
        link.click()
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href)
        document.body.removeChild(link)

        resolve()
      })
      .catch(error => {
        reject(error)
      })
  })
}
```